# What is an easy way to use SDP solvers to generate correlation matrices that satisfy some linear constraints?

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite, semidefinite-programming, cvx

Given a correlation matrix $C_0 \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n} $. I want to generate other correlation matrices $C \in \mathcal{R}^{n \times n} $ that satisfies some linear constraints of the form

$$ A_i \textbf{.} C =b_i \,\,\, i= 1,2,3...m$$  where $A_i$ is a $n \times n $ symmetric constraint matrix. <$\textbf{.}$> implies the "element wise multiplication and sum" operator, i.e. $A_i \textbf{.} C= trace (A_i^TC)$. Also, $b_i$ is a scalar.

This is similar to a semidefinite programming problem except there is no cost function involved. Hence, every point in the feasible space (the space of all real semi-definite matrices of size $n \times n$ that satisfy the linear constraints) is a viable solution.

Also, my $n$ is around 500. So I am really looking for something that is very lean and scales well. What would be the best way to do this?

I have heard of CVX ([cvx](http://cvxr.com/cvx/)) that has semidefnite solvers. But I have never used it. What is a good way to set this up?

I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/240875/116107).

Comment: I edited the question.  That link looks useful. But it minimizes a cost function.  Would it give me random samples, if I remove the const function and only run it with linear constraints?

Comment: Random? It depends on whether the SDP solver relies on randomness. You should get a feasible point. Whether you always get the same point is a question that can be answered via experimentation.